# PL/pgSQL functions - loop through specific column and execute second query in loop

Tags: postgresql, for-loop, plpgsql

As you can see in title, I want to loop through specific column which holds building IDs and then function will execute a second query that uses these looped values and show query result in PostgreSQL.

Please note that the code below:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION getBID() RETURNS SETOF building AS
$BODY$
DECLARE
    r building%ROWTYPE;
BEGIN
    FOR r IN EXECUTE 'SELECT point_id FROM building'

    LOOP

    RETURN QUERY EXECUTE 'SELECT gid, nof, year 
    FROM building 
    WHERE point_id = ' || r;

    END LOOP;
    RETURN;
END
$BODY$
LANGUAGE 'plpgsql' ;

SELECT * FROM getBID();
```

My building IDs are integer values. I wonder two aspects as follows:

- "r" variable should be declared as "integer"?
- my second query should be used in loop, too?

Thanks in advance...

Comment: Your loop doesn't make any sense. Both queries return data from the same table, so you can simply remove the first one. And the whole function can be replaced with a single `return query select gid, nof, year from building`. There is no need for a slow and cumbersome cursor

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For a trivial task like that use a [simple SQL function](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/xfunc-sql.html) instead:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION get_buildings()
  RETURNS SETOF building AS
'SELECT * FROM building' LANGUAGE sql;
```

Or just:

```
SELECT * FROM building;
```

Here is one example for an actual [`FOR` loop](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/plpgsql-control-structures.html#PLPGSQL-CONTROL-STRUCTURES-LOOPS) filling a single column in plpgsql:
[Returning results from a function in 'select statement' format](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16676573/returning-results-from-a-function-in-select-statement-format/16677220#16677220)

Another example with an anonymous record:
[Loop on tables with PL/pgSQL in Postgres 9.0+](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15266345/loop-on-tables-with-pl-pgsql-in-postgres-9/15278973#15278973)

[Try a search.](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=[plpgsql]+for+loop+declare+select) There are many more.

Comment: Could you please give me some examples that represent "for loop-approach"? Actually I need this. There are actually too many examples on internet as far as I see, but these examples substantially loop through "select * from table"-like queries. I want to understand how to loop through "select column from table"-like queries. For instance, my query'll retrieve column which holds building unique IDs and iterate over another query using these IDs. I accomplish this with python or java programming language, but I want to learn PL/pgSQL functions how to deal with this kind of cases...

Comment: @seroman: I added links to examples like you requested. Note that most of the time, a set-based approach in SQL is much faster than looping. There are exceptions ...